# c++ pointer to a function as argument

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I have a C++ API with a cThread class, and this method to create a thread:

```
void cThread::start(void(*a_function)(void), CThreadPriority a_level);
```

I've done a class and a init() method to launch a thread and an updateHaptics() method to be executed by the thread:

```
void EntryClass::init()
{
typedef void (EntryClass::*method)();
method p;
p = &EntryClass::updateHaptics;

// create a thread which starts the main haptics rendering loop
cThread* hapticsThread = new cThread();
hapticsThread->start(p, CTHREAD_PRIORITY_HAPTICS);
}

void EntryClass::updateHaptics(void)
{
    // ...  
}
```

My problem is to pass the updateHaptics() method as an argument to the cThread::start() method.

I've got this error:

`1>EntryClass.cpp(55): error C2664: 'void chai3d::cThread::start(void (__cdecl *)(void *),const chai3d::CThreadPriority,void *)' : impossible de convertir l'argument 1 de 'method' en 'void (__cdecl *)(void)'`

REM: I'm under Windows 8/Visual Studio

Comment: updateHaptics must be a function or a static method.

Comment: Unfortunately, that API is fundamentally broken, since there's no way to pass any data to the thread, and therefore no way to provide a class object to call the member function with. I'd switch to the standard thread library (or Boost, if you're stuck with an ancient compiler).

Comment: This is because, member class functions name are decorated by name of the class. Static function are not decorated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature you indicated

```
void(*a_function)(void)
```

is for a function, not for a class method. A static method will work too

Note the difference with the typedef you used:

```
void (EntryClass::*method)();
```

The definition could be:

```
class EntryClass {
public:

  void init();

  static void updateHaptics(); // <--- NOTE the static
};
```

and your implementation

```
void EntryClass::init()
{
typedef void (*method)(); // <---- NOTE THIS CHANGE
method p;
p = &EntryClass::updateHaptics;

// create a thread which starts the main haptics rendering loop
cThread* hapticsThread = new cThread();
hapticsThread->start(p, CTHREAD_PRIORITY_HAPTICS);
}

void EntryClass::updateHaptics(void)
{
    // ...  
}
```

Comment: Hi @user3714840 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, we can use only static function as a thread proc. Yes we can pass class static function also.

Comment: This should probably rather be a comment than an answer.